# Heatsink Crossing Primary and Secondary Sides in Switched-Mode Power Supply

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, safety, heatsink, clearance, creepage

[image]
I've taken apart a non-oem laptop power supply. There is clearance on the board between primary and secondary. However, they've placed a single heatsink across the board for the primary and secondary transistors. There is no insulation apart from some tape and silastic on the bulk capacitor. The heatsink is not grounded, and both trannies have plastic bodies.

1. Is this a safety issue?
2. If so, would cutting the heatsink to isolate the sides be the preferable solution (assuming transistors don't overheat)?

Thank you.

*edit:* So I decided to cut the heatsink in two, thus preventing any potential conductive paths between the two sides. I've also ordered a replacement OEM supply as the Y2 cap looked fake and there was no RF shielding.

Comment: Do Q1 and D4 have metal or plastic tabs? It is pretty hard to say from the picture.

Comment: Hi, both tabs are plastic.